# HTML select weird characters

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-forms, frontend

[image]

HTML

```
<select name="doc-step2-seniority" id="id_doc-step2-seniority" data-original-title="" title="">

<option value="Specialty Registrar" data-speciality="True">Specialty Registrar</option>

<option value="Foundation Programme" data-speciality="True">Foundation Programme</option>

<option value="Junior doctor" data-speciality="False">Junior doctor</option>

</select>
```

In addition I am using Django to display this select:

```
seniority =  forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Seniority.objects,
                                    required=True)
```

It also happens when I am doing:

```
user_title =  forms.ChoiceField(choices = [(c,c) for c in [_('Dr'),_('MD'),_('Prof'),_('Mrs'),_('Mr'),_('Ms')]], required=True)
```

I guess that the css might be the issue, as I deleted css and strange characters disapeared:

[image]

Comment: You apparently had some odd font (privately encoded font?) in use.

Comment: The text on screen is transposed by 1. I'm interested in knowing which CSS can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my own custom fonts.

Resolved.